# opencv 2.4 really slow compared to pre-built 2.3 on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm building openCV with either this script: https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-iOS-build-script, or this one: https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone.

Compared to their previous already built versions mine is really slow. The only thing I can see different is that in my case opencv is getting compiled with -O0.

Edit: I've tested it with phase correlation and lk and it's 5 times as slow.

Comment: 2.4 is in Beta. Stick with the 2.3.1 for the time being if you don't need anything specific from v2.4

Comment: I need the phase correlation module from 2.4. Also my fix would be nice, but I could apply that to 2.3.

Comment: 2.4.0 is out and it's the same thing.

Comment: Hi I just asked this quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209986/opencv-on-ios-binary-size-load-time-speed-etc What's your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use cmake as the official [documentation suggests](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html)?

**Edit:** make sure you're passing `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE` to cmake.

Comment: Same thing happens with the official release scripts. Basically running something like: mkdir aiurea; cd aiurea; ../opencv/ios/create-xcode-device.sh

Comment: are you sure you're making a release version? see the edited answer please.

Comment: I just tried it out. Added -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE and it's the same thing. Here is some compile output: http://pastebin.com/M7qckRGB

Comment: Did you remember to empty the aiurea directory? ran cmake in a new/empty directory?

Comment: I can provide with the two different builds to test the difference. It's incredibly noticeable.

Comment: I'm busy now, and cant do this, but you can investigate and see why the optimization flags are not passed to the compiler. Need to check the cmake script.

Comment: I've been trying but I can't figure it out. Maybe it's something related to my dev environment.